# assigned a null value to object and then try to do unboxing

Tags: java

If I have assigned a `null` value to an Object like

```
Integer t=new Integer(null);
```

How can I change this Object to Int primitive data type now (Unboxing) ?

Comment: This will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Just as with every other `Integer`, just expect a NullPointerException on the way. Like `Integer I = null; int i = I;`

Answer (score 7):

I think you will find that this throws a `NumberFormatException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Integer i = new Integer(null);
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

So, to answer your question, you cannot as your `Integer` is never created. I.e. the first statement in your question is false: *If I have assigned a `null` value to an Object*. You have not.

You might mean something different:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Integer i = null;
    final int ii = i;
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException`, output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

As `int` cannot be `null`, when the unboxing happens (essentially a call to `i.intValue()`) an NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Object obj = null; // maybe not null??
Integer t=new Integer(null ? 0 : obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code wont work and it will throw **java.lang.NumberFormatException:** at the line `Integer t=new Integer(null);`.
Exception is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

You asked

> How can I change this Object to Int primitive data type now (Unboxing)?

A safe method to **unbox null Integer objects** i.e. **changing this Object to Int** primitive data try this,

```
Integer t=new Integer(null);
int a= (int)( t == null ? 0 : t) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer t=new Integer(null);` throws a `NumberFormatException` since this constructor expects a non-null `String` as input.

If you need to create an `Integer` from something that can be `null`, use this code:

```
 Integer t = new Integer( null == input ? "0" : input );
```

Unboxing this is then always safe.

If you have an `Integer` which can be null, then you need to use this code:

```
int value = ( null == t ? 0 : t.intValue() );
```

as auto-unboxing will not work in this case.